# Почему иногда срабатывает исключение InterruptedException

Tags: java, многопоточность

Почему иногда срабатывает исключение InterruptedException, ведь Thread.interrupted() проверяет флаг прерывания и тут же сбрасывает?

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread threadExample = new Thread(new JoinClass());
        threadExample.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        threadExample.interrupt();
    }
}
class JoinClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run.." + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        while (!Thread.interrupted());
        System.out.println("end while.." + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("try..");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("catch..");
        }
        System.out.println("end run.." + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
    }
}
```

---

```
run..false
end while..false
catch..false
end run..false
```

Comment: А это что `threadExample.interrupt();`?

Comment: Устанавливаем флаг прерывания true, в потоке в цикле while(!Thread.interrupted()); проверяем его и сбрасываем false. далее выходим из цикла и засыпаем sleep(100). Почему sleep реагирует на флаг, ведь он уже в значение false?

Comment: Вывод `catch..false` точно из этого примера? Откуда взялся `false` если `System.out.println("catch..");`?

Comment: из этого, немного код подредактировал. Исключение летит не всегда, вот и вопрос почему так?

Comment: Приведенный код не может выбросить `InterruptedException()`. Видимо он не _немного подредактирован_.